# Is it possible to create a price filter with Ubercart 2 and Drupal 6?

Tags: php, drupal, view, e-commerce, ubercart

I'm currently building an e-commerce site with Drupal 6.21, Ubercart 6.x-2.4, and Views 6.x-2.12 as the main components. I've been asked to create a "Narrow by price" section for each product category within ubercart, however I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

For instance the filters could be (Teddies is the main product category) -

All teddies,
Teddies between £0 - £10,
Teddies between £10 - £50,
Teddies between £50 - £100,
Over £100.

There are different sub categories under Teddies such as bears, elephants, etc which is working as expected, however I can't figure out how to filter as above.

I'm using Ubercart Advanced Catalog 6.x-1.x-dev to get better Views integration however this doesn't seem to help with the problem as I thought it might.

Thanks for any help you can give, and if you need more info please ask :-) Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try http://drupal.org/project/uc_views, I don't have experience with ubercart advanced Catalog, but that's a great module to expose a lot information to views, some of which are the product prices, so you should be able to build any listing you want.

I am assuming you know how to work with views.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had a look and already had that module installed. I've ended up creating a taxonomy for each price and just making a block for each product category until I can figure this out. There really should be a default behaviour that allows this :-(